# Multiple Questions per page using Drupal Quiz

Tags: drupal

I'm using the Drupal Quiz module, and have setup some basic quizzes and stuff like that.  However some further customization is required, involving more than 1 question per page, and a multi-type answer in this type of format:

Question 1: Describe 4 things you did last summer
a) [ short answer space - text field ]
b) "I wept"
c) "My whole family died so I learned self reliance"
d) "I got another xbox"

Question 2: Describe 2 things you hate about yourself
a) "My arms are way shorter than my legs"
b) "I was born without human emotion"

So I guess in two parts, how to show multiple questions per page, and then how to allow multiple text fields for answers.  Oh and this quiz is not graded, it's like a self assessment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find that [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) better suits your needs

Comment: Problem is, webform doesn't support a lot of the Quiz features like resume.  I'm leaning towards writing custom question types, but that may not solve the issue of showing multiple questions per page still.

Comment: I ended up using Webform, and sorta hacked it together using Rules.  If you know of a better way of grouping forms together that'd be helpful, since we didn't want the user to have to finish the whole form at once, and the "next" & "previous", from my tests, don't seem to save until you hit "save" at the end.

Comment: Ok I got rid of the Rules bit, since that was really hacky.  The way I went is to just write a simple custom module and use hook_form_alter to adjust the form redirect to the next page.  I just store a list of nid's globally for each grouping of quizzes.

Comment: Andrew...can you share this module? It will be of help as this is exactly what I am trying to create, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is available in quiz 5, add a quiz page and later add questions to it.
can follow hierarchy to add multiple questions to a single quiz page.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this answer is 3 years late, but I think it might still be helpful to someone, take a look at this [comment](http://drupal.org/node/503228#comment-6722190), i tried it and worked for my project, but there's a little bug for "allow resume" for showing all question in a single page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Quiz Page" content type. Then "Add a content" to "Quiz Page". Go to your quiz and then to "Manage question". Add this newly created question "Quiz Page" to the quiz. Now you can simply drag all other question underneath this "Quiz Page" question.